# Select Option with PHP when the markup is built

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7, selected

NEW TO PHP (selection and form)
Here's my problem:

Let's say that I have a select element with some option list and, based on the page that I'm in, I want to automatic select my option:

```
<select name="program_">
    <option value="myvalue">my value</option>
    <option value="myvalue2">my other value</option>
    <option value="myvalue3">my last value</option>
</select>
```

I created a script based on a plugin that I'm using for custom post and field, and it works in this way (PHP):

```
            <?php if (CFS()->get( 'program_code' )): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo CFS()->get( 'program_code' ) ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo CFS()->get( 'program_code' ) ?></option>"
            <?php else: ?>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Program of interest *</option>"
            <?php endif; ?>
```

And I added right after my  tag.

Now, it works fine but the problem is that it duplicate my field. Essentially the final mark up will be, based on the dinamic sidebar that it will create something like that:

```
<select name="program_">
        <option value="myvalue" selected="selected">my value</option>
        <option value="myvalue">my value</option>
        <option value="myvalue2">my other value</option>
        <option value="myvalue3">my last value</option>
</select>
```

Like I said the script will duplicate the value, instead I would love to create only the value that I need to add to my selection.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

PLUS, it is gonna add the element at the beginning of the list, and I'd like to select my option in the exact position where the option selected is found.

Comment: Do a loop through your code, and then check if the current value === the selected value, and just set that `<option />` with `selected="selected"` (Don't make any special if/else statements at the top of the loop to put the selected index at the top)

Comment: You should show more of your PHP (more of what's before and after what you posted). What you posted alone wouldn't generate the output you're showing.

Comment: sure, like how? it is html, where should I start to loop through?

Answer (score 0):

The  meaning of your if/else code is to test if that condition EXISTS.

If you want to code for several conditions, you need the FOR loop.